# c# mvc why are urls combining when requested?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

This is my first time developing something in C# and in MVC. I deployed my application and everything seems to be functioning ok except for the navigation. The first thing you click on will direct you properly, but the second time will try to combine the pathing request with the first.

Ex. Clicking on Services drop down and click ProcessReports correctly returns the web page, with the URL:

```
http://{ServerName}/SupportPortal/Support/ProcessReports
```

Then, clicking on a dropdown and then DalimWebApp Dev returns a 404 error and the url is

```
http://{ServerName}/SupportPortal/Support/Support/DalimWebApp/Dev
```

Why are there two "Supports?"
Any ideas?

Comment: How are you building the URLs in the navigation links?  Are you using one of the helpers (like Url.Action or Html.ActionLink) or are you building the links yourself?

Answer (score 1):

How are you generating the URL for your links?

If you're using an HTML anchor with an href value "Support/ProcessReports" instead of "/Support/ProcessReports" (mind the forward slash) the URLs will be relative to your current path. Try prepending the forward slash.

As @David mentioned, you could also use the built in helpers to generate the entire link for you if it's easier for you.

Comment: That was it, the forward slashes do matter. Thanks for you help.